# Upload/Create files in CodeCommit repo using CloudFormation

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit

I have a CloudFormation template that makes a CodePipeline pipeline, including a CodeCommit repo as the source code. I have the CloudFormation template making the repo, but even after reading the documentation linked to [in this announcement of the functionality][1] I'm still completely at a loss as to what to do to make it so that the CodeCommit has an initial commit holding the three files (two JSON, one python) that I need to run upon starting the CloudFormation. How do I link to the s3 bucket from my template? Alternatively, anyone know if I could hypothetically stick the full text of the three code files in the CloudFormation template? Any solution that gets it to commit the documents upon starting would be acceptable. The part of my template that makes the repo looks like this:

````
        Type: "AWS::CodeCommit::Repository"
        Properties:
            RepositoryName: "ID"
            RepositoryDescription: "Holds template for CloudFormation, buildspec, and Lambda for IDAPI" ```



  [1]: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/10/aws-identity-and-access-management-iam-policy-simulator-now-helps-you-test-resource-level-permissions/#:~:text=Using%20the%20IAM%20policy%20simulator,that%20you%20wish%20to%20verify.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload your three files in a zip package into S3. Then, in the CloudFormation you will reference that when you create your repo in [Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codecommit-repository-code.html) parameter.

For example:

```
        Type: "AWS::CodeCommit::Repository"
        Properties:
          RepositoryName: "ID"
          RepositoryDescription: "Holds template for CloudFormation, buildspec, and Lambda for IDAPI" 
          Code:
            S3:
              Bucket: <bucket-with-your-zip> 
              Key: <key-of-the-zip> # aka filename
              ObjectVersion: <version-number> # optional version number
```